# Is there any API from Trucaller to get user details?

Tags: python, flask, verification

I need to verify user details inside a Flask based website in python. For that I need to call Truecaller via its API. I have seen Truecaller SDK, but is there any way to implement user verification using Truecaller, inside Python Flask website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no existing libraries that make this easy (as in, no plug and play libraries like flask_recaptcha), so in short no there isn't an easy way that you are looking for.

I am not recommending any api outside of its official flow process through their dev. portal, since scraping is strictly prohibited by their ToS.

> Scraping of any information contained in the Services, by use of automated systems or software to extract data, including any Content and any third party information accessible via the Services, is strictly prohibited.

There is, however, existing documentation about your request, but with Django and not Flask. Even better, there is options to implement it manually into your source code yourself. Thus, there is three possible ways to go from here, and I already got you started with some basic sources:

1. Switch to Django - see https://github.com/sumansaurabh/TrueCallerAPi - https://shashank-sharma.xyz/2018/05/01/using-truecaller-sdk-with-django-and-heroku/
2. Implement the flow process manually into your WebAPP (The most likely option in your situation) - see - https://developer.truecaller.com/ - https://medium.com/@hardychugh34/adding-truecaller-login-to-your-web-app-5e15e2c14ad0
3. Switch to an alternative service with an easy to use api - http://www.callerpy.io/#about

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had tried all of them but sadly had no luck to go through it. But I will be marking this answer correct, because Truecaller really does not support user verification other than their SDK for android apps.

Answer (score 3):

Try truecallerpy

```
pip install truecallerpy
```

```py
from truecallerpy import search_phonenumber

id = "Your installationId at here"
# To know your installation id run `truecallerpy -i` on terminal or command prompt

# search_phonenumber( "PHONE_NUMBER","COUNTRY_CODE","INSTALLATION_ID")

search_phonenumber("9912345678","IN", id)

# ==> search_phonenumber("+12093031250","IN", id)
```

For more information https://github.com/sumithemmadi/truecallerpy